# Hibernate Foreign Key not updating on SaveOrUpdate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I've got a Parent/Child relationship declared in my hibernate mappings. The Parent contains a collection of Child objects. When I create and save a new parent that contains new child objects, I get an error:

> Cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA"."ACCESS_LIST_MEMBERS"."LIST_ID")

Here is the parent mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="AccessLists" optimistic-lock="version" schema="schema" table="ACCESS_LISTS">
<id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
  <column name="ID" precision="38" scale="0"/>
  <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">ACCESS_LISTS_SEQ</param>
  </generator>
</id>
<property name="userId" type="java.lang.Integer">
  <column name="USER_ID" not-null="true" precision="38" scale="0"/>
</property>
<property name="name" type="string">
  <column length="30" name="NAME" not-null="true"/>
</property>
<set name="accessListMembers" cascade="all" table="ACCESS_LIST_MEMBERS" inverse="false" fetch="select">
    <key>
        <column name="LIST_ID" precision="38" scale="0" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="AccessListMembers"  />
</set>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The child mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="AccessListMembers" optimistic-lock="version" schema="schema" table="ACCESS_LIST_MEMBERS">    
<id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
  <column name="ID" />
  <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">ACCESS_LIST_MBRS_SEQ</param>
  </generator>
</id>
<property name="listId" type="java.lang.Integer">
    <column name="LIST_ID" not-null="true" />
</property>
<property name="wwid" type="string">
  <column length="5" name="WWID" not-null="true"/>
</property>
<join table="AccessLists" inverse="true">
        <key column="ID"/>
        <many-to-one name="accessList" column="LIST_ID" not-null="true"/>
</join>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I thought adding the **join** information in the child mapping would let hibernate know to get the LIST_ID from the parent object ACCESS_LIST.ID but this does not happen. I get the error upon executing this code:

```
public static void saveList(AccessLists list) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    try {
        session.saveOrUpdate(list);
        tx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tx.rollback();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I do not want to have to manually set the LIST_ID on each of the objects in the AccessListMembers collection on AccessList. I've gone through the JBOSS documentation but I think I have misunderstood how the one-to-many and many-to-one relationships work.

How can I setup my mappings so that hibernate knows to perform an INSERT on AccessList, update the LIST_ID on AccessListMembers, and perform an INSERT on AccessListMembers?

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: @PeterRader Not an efficient one that could be handled by using the Hibernate mappings. More and more often I find this is an issue with parent / child collections and hibernate but nobody has been able to provide me with a solid solution.

Answer (score 1):

You must double-bound the parent and the child. You bound the child to the parent, ok - but you did not bound the parent to the child like this:

```
accessListMember.setList(accessList);
```

By the way, you may need a tech-review and introduce IoC. It is a old, mystic and dangerous knowledge to use transactions by yourself. I saw programmers must use transactions because they had to use transactional savepoints, if it is your case, have fun.

Comment: I looped over each child and did a accessListMember.setAccessList(list) but this did not work. Doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose of mappings? What if I had a 1000 item collection? I don't think I should have to loop the entire thing because I could just save each individually.

Comment: @Encryption You are using `cascade=all` so you shall not save each of the 1000 accessListMember by manual. What you describe shall not throw this exception. I might be interrested in the sequence `ACCESS_LIST_MBRS_SEQ`, are you sure `NULL` is invalid in the sequence?